# Defining a new command using a conditional

Tags: macros, conditionals

I want to define a new command (to be used **only in mathmode**), the execution of which depends on the input given to it. Particularly, I want to define `\F` as

```
\newcommand{\F}[1]{F#1}
```

if the first character in its input is `(` , and as

```
\newcommand{\F}[1]{F(#1)}
```

if the first character in its input is not `(` .

As an example, I would like `\F{x}` to output `F(x)` and `\F{(x)}` to output `F(x)`.

I have no idea how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No packages required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\F[1]{\Faux#1\endFaux}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Faux{\@ifnextchar(\Fnoadd\Fadd}
\makeatother
\def\Fadd#1\endFaux{F(#1)}
\def\Fnoadd#1\endFaux{F#1}
\begin{document}
$\F{(x)}$ $\F{(G(x))}$

$\F{x}$ $\F{G(x)}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the following code:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\F}[1]{
    \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstletter]%
    \StrRight{#1}{1}[\lastletter]%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{(}{\firstletter} \AND \equal{)}{\lastletter}}{F#1}{F(#1)}%
}
```

It basically checks what the first and last characters of the argument are, and if those are '(' and ')', it will output the argument without extra parentheses.

Comment: Since I cannot accept two answers, I've upvoted your answer. I accepted the other answer since it doesn't require a package. Thank you though.